# Apollo client / AWS AppSync JavaScript SDK altering query result

Tags: graphql, apollo, aws-appsync

I am executing a simple query that returns correctly using the AppSync console, but when I execute the same query from within my application the data is returned incorrectly. Specifically, there is an array of a child type in the object being returned and while the number of instances in the array is correct, each instance is a copy of the first instance.

I have disabled local caching on the client and removed the first instance from the array in the database and when I run the query in the console it works fine, but the problem persists in the application (though with the new first instance now being copied).

Console output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getTemplates": [
      {
        "name": "test template",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Assigned User",
            "format": "String"
          },
          {
            "name": "Office",
            "format": "String"
          },
          {
            "name": "Department",
            "format": "String"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Browser log output from the application:

```
0
:
{id: null, name: "Assigned User", format: "String", __typename: "Field", Symbol(id): "Field:null"}
1
:
{id: null, name: "Assigned User", format: "String", __typename: "Field", Symbol(id): "Field:null"}
2
:
{id: null, name: "Assigned User", format: "String", __typename: "Field", Symbol(id): "Field:null"}
```

Query and logging code:

```
<Query query={getTemplatesQuery}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return null;
        if (error) return `Error: ${error}`;

        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.getTemplates);
        return (
            <DataTable data={data.getTemplates} />
        );
    }}
</Query>
```

Query, copy pasted from application to console for testing:

```
{
    getTemplates {
        id
        name
        author
        data {
            id
            name
            format
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on that could be causing this? Is there an easy way to test this from another client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo's cache does a [normalization process](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#normalization)

> By default, InMemoryCache will attempt to use the commonly found primary keys of `id` and `_id` for the unique identifier if they exist along with `__typename` on an object.

Since the results you are returning don't have an id field, the key used for them is `"Field:null"`, for all of them.

The solution in this case is to return an id in your `Field` children (in the logs you pasted their value is `null`). Or, use `dataIdFromObject` to give hints to the cache on how to generate cache keys for your objects.